# Fridge Icing Up

Tags: refrigerator, ice

Why am I getting this ice in the bottom of the inside back of the refrigerator (not freezer) section of my Whirlpool WRS970CIDH side-by-side?  It's only a little over a year old.

[image: fridge ice]

When I read online, the primary reason for this is that the doors aren't closed properly, they feel like they close correctly.  I did wonder about these little Styrofoam pieces, they seem to be pretty well attached like they're supposed to be there:

[image: fridge doors]

Comment: In most of these the usual cause is that the frost sensor has failed.

Comment: You say there's only ice/frost in the refrigerator section,and the freezer section is clear?

Comment: What are the styrofoam blocks attached to? If on the doorframe that may be your problem, Hard to tell from the pic but usually they're removed during installation. With the door closed the rubber door seal should be flush against the cabinet - is it?

Comment: I thought most refrigerators (maybe the newer high-end ones are different) just run through the defrost cycle on a time basis, like once every 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Those foam blocks look like shipping blocks to me, not normally left in place.
Once defrosted will this happen again?
There are a few possibilities, a fan that circulates the air failing is one possibility and a second is a defrost timer failure can also cause this. I would check and see if the fridge is still under warranty. But if those foam blocks are close to the door I would remove them they are not a sanitary kind of item if the doors are held open even slightly it will freeze up and the defrost timer probably could not keep up with the frost buildup.